# a:visited behaving strange in browsers ( works in IE 10 tho..)

Tags: html, css

in short, I want each link to have it's own style and im using pseudocasses a:link, a:visited.

Each link has its own class as well (*.prvo* and *.drugo*)

```
.prvo:link {color: green; border: 2px solid green; padding:10px}
.prvo:visited {color: red; border-color: red; }
.prvo:hover{}
.prvo:active{}

.drugo:link {color: blue; border: 2px dashed blue; padding:10px; }
.drugo:visited {color: orange; border-color: orange;}
.drugo:hover{}
.drugo:active{}
```

Problem: when i click first link, second changes color as well to his a:visited color, which I dont want ofc.

It works as I was expecting onlly in IE 10.

[CODEPEN code here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBGdrb?editors=110)

Help, what am I missing out there...

Comment: They both link to the same place so of course the browser considers the link visited.

Comment: TY, ty ..ty....whaat a n00b mistake on my part!  holly molly..

Comment: The `:visited` pseudo class is applied when the URL has been visited, and is therefore **element/selector agnostic**. As long as the URL is non-unique, the pseudoclass will be applied to all anchor elements with that URL.

Comment: Yea, once again, ty all for fast response, such obvious problem I've missed with those dummy links... Ehh...*hides away in a shame*...

Answer (score 1):

This is because both of those links refer to the same place. If You click in one of them, second will be "visited" also.